# Type inference fails with variable number of arguments in case of a single argument

Tags: swift

Consider the following code (I'm posting this mostly as a matter of insight into the hurdles Swift compiler has to overcome – the failure itself is unlikely to affect too many developers):

```
extension Int {
    static var i: Int { return 5 }
}

func f(#xs: Int...) { // notice the #
    println(xs)
}

f(xs: .i, .i, .i)   // --> [5, 5, 5]
f()                 // --> []
f(xs: 5)            // --> [5]
f(xs: .i)           // --> [5]

func g(xs: Int...) { // no #
    println(xs)
}

g(.i, .i, .i)       // --> [5, 5, 5]
g()                 // --> []
g(5)                // --> [5]
g(.i)               // --> error: '(Int...).Type' does not have a member named 'i'
```

So the question is whether you would regard this as a bug? To that end, consider that the problem may be related to:

```
let (xs: Int...) = (.max, .min)
xs // --> [9223372036854775807, -9223372036854775808]
```

whereas with a single element, the compiler does not interpret the parens as defining a tuple (which, in itself, is a feature of the language, not a bug):

```
let (xs: Int...) = (.max) // error: could not find member 'max'
```

and so, with the explicit type we can just as well remove the parens:

```
let (xs: Int...) = Int.max
xs // --> [9223372036854775807]
```

**Workaround**
(inspired by Airspeed Velocity - see his/her fine answer below)

```
func h(xs: [Int]) {
    println(xs)
}

func h(x: Int, xs: Int...) {
    h([x] + xs)
}

func h() {
    h([])
}

h(.i, .i, .i)   // --> [5, 5, 5]
h(.i, .i)       // --> [5, 5]
h(.i)           // --> [5]
h()             // --> []
```

**Example use case**

```
import Foundation

public extension NSRegularExpressionOptions { // these are nil literal convertible!

    static var i: NSRegularExpressionOptions { return .CaseInsensitive }
    static var x: NSRegularExpressionOptions { return .AllowCommentsAndWhitespace }
    //  static var IgnoreMetacharacters: NSRegularExpressionOptions { get }
    static var s: NSRegularExpressionOptions { return .DotMatchesLineSeparators }
    static var m: NSRegularExpressionOptions { return .AnchorsMatchLines }
    //  static var UseUnixLineSeparators: NSRegularExpressionOptions { get }
    static var u: NSRegularExpressionOptions { return .UseUnicodeWordBoundaries }
}

public extension String {

    // TODO: implement named capture groups (?<name>pattern)
    func r(options: [NSRegularExpressionOptions]) -> NSRegularExpression {
        return NSRegularExpression(pattern: self, options: reduce(options, nil, |), error: nil)!
    }

    func r(option: NSRegularExpressionOptions, _ options: NSRegularExpressionOptions...) -> NSRegularExpression {
        return r(options + [option])
    }

    func r() -> NSRegularExpression { return r([]) }

    var r: NSRegularExpression { return r([]) }
}

"a\\s+$".r(.m | .i) // --> NSRegularExpression

"a\\s+$".r(.m, .i)  // --> NSRegularExpression

"\\s+$".r(.m)       // --> NSRegularExpression

"\\s+".r()          // --> NSRegularExpression

"\\s+".r            // --> NSRegularExpression
```

Not that you would necessarily need or want all these options :) In fact, I can't resist adding:

```
public func / (lhs: String, rhs: NSRegularExpressionOptions) -> NSRegularExpression {
    return lhs.r(rhs)
}

public extension NSRegularExpressionOptions {
    static var r: NSRegularExpressionOptions { return .allZeros }
}

"\\s+" / .r             // --> NSRegularExpression
"\\s+$" / .m            // --> NSRegularExpression
"a\\s+$" / (.m | .i)    // --> NSRegularExpression
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see it in 1.2 also.  But I'm not certain it’s a bug either, though the compiler error could be better.

The implicit member abbreviation only kicks in when the type on the left can be completely unambiguously identified.  But since functions can take a tuple as an argument (i.e. `func f(_: Int, _: Int) { }; let x = (1,2); f(x)`) there are two possibilities (`Int` and `Int...`).

Naming the argument, or passing in multiple arguments, makes it clear you’re not trying to pass in an `(Int...)`, so the type to the left of `.i` is unambiguously `Int` and the implicit member abbreviation works.

Similarly this also works: `func h(_: Int, xs: Int...) { }; h(1, .i)`.  As does `g(.i as Int)`.

You’d get a similar error message if you tried this: `func generic<T>(x: T) { }; g(.i)` – just because there happens to be one possible match doesn’t mean Swift is willing to pick it out of multiple possibilities.

Then again, this argument is undermined by this working just fine:  `func k(i: Int) {  }; func k(d: Double) { }; k(.i)`.  So perhaps it is a bug – but it's debatable anyway.

Comment: Thanks for giving this a thought... Yes, the error clearly shows that the argument type is interpreted as a tuple. Though I agree this is debatable, the examples do raise a clear expectation that the case of the single argument should be interpreted as all the others – as an `Int` rather than an `(Int...)`. For example, I have an extension of `String` that returns an `NSRegularExpression` using `self` as a pattern and I'd love to be able to pass `(.i)` instead of `(NSRegularExpressionOptions.CaseInsensitive)`. This works in all other cases, such as `( )` or `(.i, .m)`, or even `(.i, nil)`...